# Can I stop Bevy from using the CPU when there is no need to redraw the screen?

Tags: rust, bevy

I'm just looking at the examples in Bevy, and I tried one of them with

```
$ cargo run --example blend_modes -r
```

and I noticed that it shows 30% CPU usage even when the screen does not change. I think that my potential users will have the expectation that an open but idle program won't drain their laptop battery too fast, and will find it annoying if it does.

So I'm wondering if this behavior is an inherent limitation of the engine, or if `blend_modes.rs` can be fixed so as to avoid unnecessary CPU usage?

Comment: This might be one of those instances where a single directional language that only transmits on page submit would excel.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a [`WinitSettings`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/winit/struct.WinitSettings.html) resource with the appropriate [`UpdateMode`s](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/winit/enum.UpdateMode.html) set.

For example:

```rust
App::new()
    .insert_resource(WinitSettings::desktop_app())
```

Note that this will cause your systems to run only when input happens in your window.

Comment: I tried this with the `load_gltf` example, and it looks like it's still redraws once every few seconds? This is probably precisely what I want, but just to make sure your answer is factually correct can you double-check this part: *"will cause your systems to run only when input happens in your window"* (Also what do you mean by "systems" here?)

Comment: @MWB As you can read in the docs for UpdateMode, there is an upper limit to the amount of time that the engine will wait for input before running an update anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Am I understanding correctly that this is configured at app launch and cannot be changed while it's running? Suppose the user is setting up some kind of animation in 3D, plays it, and then goes back to interacting with the screen -- can Bevy switch between the most appropriate configurations?

Comment: @MWB `WinitSettings` is set as a "resource" so you should be able to mutate it as you deem fit via a system with [`ResMut`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/ecs/system/struct.ResMut.html).